# Using variables as flags in Batch files

Tags: batch-file, dos

I am writing a Batch file that parses through a text file and produces an output only when it reads a particular line in the said file. Consider the following text file named *sample.txt*:

```
List1
Dog
Cat
Monkey

List2
Horse
Bear
Dog
Pig
Dog
```

Let's say that the objective of my Batch file is to output how many times the word "Dog" appears in each list. So in *sample.txt* there are two lists: one has 1 instance of "Dog" and the other has 2. To implement this in a batch file, I wrote the following:

```
@echo off
set count=0
set first_iteration=1

for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (sample.txt) do (
    echo %%A > tempfile.txt

    FINDSTR /R ".*List.*" tempfile.txt > NUL

    REM If true, this is a list header
    if errorlevel 1 (
        if %first_iteration% EQU 1 (
            REM PROBLEM HAPPENS HERE
            set first_iteration=0
        ) else (
            echo %count% >> log.txt
            set count=0 
        )
    REM An animal has been found
    ) else (
        FINDSTR /R ".Dog.*" tempfile.txt > NUL
        if NOT errorlevel 1  (
            set \A count+=1
        )
    )
)
del tempfile.txt
echo %count% >> log.txt
pause
```

So basically how this code works is that I have to print out how many "Dogs" have been found by the time it reads a new list header (List1 and List2). The first time this happens the count will be zero because it is also the first line of the *sample.txt* file. For example, after List1 is read, it keeps reading until it finds List2, by which the count is 1. Then the count resets to 0 because it is reading through a new list. By the time the Batch file reads through the second list, since it is also the final list, it needs to output whatever count it has.

The *first_iteration* variable keeps track of whether the batch file is reading through the first list so that it knows when not to output *count*. But the problem is, the value of *first_iteration* does not change because of how Batch interprets variable values in a single line command (if you look closely all if/else statements are enclosed in a single set of brackets).

So is there a way to implement my objective in the form of a Batch file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `!first_iteration!` for delayed evaluation.  You need to use it several places in your script after using `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` to enable it.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set count=0
set first_iteration=1

for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (sample.txt) do (
    echo %%A > tempfile.txt

    FINDSTR /R ".*List.*" tempfile.txt > NUL

    REM If true, this is a list header
    REM your post was missing the NOT here
    if NOT errorlevel 1 (
        if !first_iteration! EQU 1 (
            SET first_iteration=0
        ) else (
            echo !count! >> log.txt
            set count=0 
        )
    REM An animal has been found
    ) else (
        REM your post was missing the first * on this line
        FINDSTR /R ".*Dog.*" tempfile.txt > NUL
        if NOT errorlevel 1 (
            REM your post used a \ instead of a / here
            set /A count=1+!count!
        )
   )
)
del tempfile.txt
echo %count% >> log.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

> Let's say that the objective of my Batch file is to output how many
>   times the word "Dog" appears in each list.

```
SET counter=0
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F "USEBACKQ tokens=*" %%F IN (`TYPE "C:\Folder\sample.txt" ^| FIND /I "dog"`) DO (
  SET /a counter=!counter!+1
)
ECHO Dog shows up !counter! many times in this file.
```

Didn't test... can't remember if you're supposed to use ! or % when calling counter after the loop...